# Publish dotnet core with specific minor version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I want to publish a dotnet core project with a speicific minor version (3.1.1).
The project needs to run on a machine which has that version installed, which I cannot upgrade.
Currently my VS only publishes dlls with target version 3.1.5, and I cannot seem to be able to change that.
I tried downgrading my installed dotnet core sdk version but that didn't work either.

Comment: Version version of the SDK are you using to build your app? `dotnet --version`

Comment: global.json may help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection

Comment: @freakzoid, Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following steps to publish .net core 3.1.1 version project.

First, please use the following command to check if your computer exists .net core sdks  version 3.1.101:(If not exist, please install it)

```
dotnet --info
```

Second, you can create a global.json in the current directory setting the SDK version to 3.1.101:

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.1.101
```

Finally, you can publish your project:

```
dotnet publish
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to publish your project framework independent.

Just edit your publish-options. (change framework-dependent to self-contained)

You can also use this code:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

references:

https://gunnarpeipman.com/dotnet-core-self-contained-executable/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained